# Comparing through a derived class method

Tags: python-3.x

In my assignment we have to program Go Fish from some example blackjack classes and I'm trying to make a method that compares the card I selected from the target instance. It seems to go through the list but does not take my input.

Here is my class

```
class GF_Hand(Hand):
def compare(self, Guess):
    for card in self.cards:
        if Guess == card :
            print("Match Found")
            return Guess

        else:
            print(card,"Match not found")
```

and here is the method invoked

```
test = player2.compare(guess)
```

It comes up in the end with No Match despite me selecting the correct card
, I've been stuck for hours on this assignment and didn't have trouble with the language until I arrived into the OOP scene now i'm really confused.

Comment: `Card` is not `card`.

Comment: oops I was messing with some context,  it matches now but the result doesn't change.   Goes through the list of cards and wont compare to the input given.